# JSF unique input bean for each item in a loop

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to iterate over a list of elements and for each element I want to display a form. In that form I want to be able to fill a bean that is different for each element of the loop. Here's what I got so far but of course it doesn't work ;)

```
    <ui:repeat value="#{productBean.productPositions}" var="position">
        <div>position info here</div>
        <div>list price ranges</div>
        <div>
            <h5>Create new price range for product position position</h5>
            <h:form>
                Min:
                <h:inputText
                    value="#{priceRangeBean.priceRanges[productPositionRangeSearch.productPositions.indexOf(position)].min}" />
                Max:
                <h:inputText
                    value="#{priceRangeBean.priceRanges[productPositionRangeSearch.productPositions.indexOf(position)].max}" />
                price:
                <h:inputText
                    value="#{priceRangeBean.priceRanges[productPositionRangeSearch.productPositions.indexOf(position)].price}" />
                <h:commandButton value="create"
                    action="#{priceRangeController.createRange(productPositionRangeSearch.productPositions.indexOf(position))}" />
            </h:form>

        </div>
    </ui:repeat>
```

my PriceRangeBean:

```
@SessionScope
public class PriceRangeBean {

    private List<PriceRange> priceRanges = new ArrayList<PriceRange>();

    public List<PriceRange> getPriceRanges() {
        return priceRanges;
    }

    public void setPriceRanges(List<PriceRange> priceRanges) {
        this.priceRanges = priceRanges;
    }

}
```

with `PriceRange` being a POJO containing min, max, price as `String`

The controller calling the page fills the `PriceRangeBean` with as many `PriceRange`s as there are `ProductPosition`s so that there is a "new" `PriceRange` Object in the list ready to be created. However the input doesn't seem to reach the backing bean.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not use this kind of EL expression for the `value` property in the `<h:inputText`.

The expression:

```
 value="#{priceRangeBean.priceRanges[productPositionRangeSearch.productPositions.indexOf(position)].min}"
```

is (at least) evaluated two times. 
Once when the value needs to be set in the "apply request values". And a second time in the "render response phase".

When the value is set (in the apply request values phase) the expression is evaluated by the EL as an `lvalue` and that seems to have limited capabilities.

From the Spec [(JavaServer Pages 2.1 Expression Language Specification)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/):

> an lvalue can only consist of either a single variable (e.g. ${name}) or a
>   property resolution.

You may want to check out the section 1.2.1.1 in that same spec.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Was afraid it would be something like this.. Any ideas on how I can achieve my task of having a dynamic amount of beans to hold the input of a dynamic amount of forms? ;)

Comment: We had a case where we only had a fixed number of objects in the list/array. For the sake of simplicity we just kicked out the list/array and went along with using the objects directly. So, I don't really have an idea at hand. sorry.